# Long installation time on Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one

My Xbox One was taking 8-12 hours to install a game.

I thought it may have been a faulty console, but I had the shop replace it, and it still takes as long.

Star Wars: Battlefront has taken 10 hours to reach 36%. I am use to PlayStation; is this normal for an Xbox One?

Comment: Are you talking about installing the games on to the Xbox one?

Comment: Or maybe about downloading games?

Comment: Ive experienced really long installation and download times compared to a friend on a different ISP a few miles away, ports open, same speed connection. No idea why really but ISP seems the likely culprit. Hard to say without detailed network stats.

Comment: It should never take even _ONE_ hour to launch the Xbox or game. Also flagging as unclear

Comment: @Alex, read the whole question. OP is inserting a game **for the first time**. The first time, the xbox needs to install the game. I know that some games actually require an internet connection for this process, and have not asked me to confirm updates; however, I can not confirm that anything downloads.

Comment: OP, I have changed your question to ask about installation (given that you are trying on a brand new xbox, and refer to installation progress); can you confirm if you have tried other games, or just battlefront? Given that battlefront is an online game, its possible you are required to perform all updates during installation. If you have bad internet, that can happen

Comment: @Timelord64 the original post says 8-12 hours to LOAD a game

Comment: @Alex, with a basic understanding of the environment, it is easy to infer OPs intentions to clean up the question. I am going to break it into three major clues, in case it gives you a bit more understanding.

Comment: **OP reports this happening on a new console**: The first time you attempt to play a game on Xbox One (PlayStation 4, as well, AFAIK), the console starts installing the game. This process is still displayed as a "loading bar", and users could easily misdiagnose the process as "loading".

Comment: **The times reported are illogical for a game "loading", but make sense as  "installing" times**: Lets be realistic. No game takes that long to load. In my experience, the console will report an error, much earlier. This could be a faulty console, but OP reports having the console replaced. The chances of both having the same problem are unlikely. **8-12 hours is definitely a potential installation time**, although IMO highly unlikely for a brand new console. As I previously commented, I believe the installation is including online content, and that OPs internet just can not keep up.

Comment: Lastly, **Battlefront does not report a percentage, when loading**. Having played the game a couple of times, at a friends, the initial loading is literally a splash screen and a 10-30 second wait. When installing, however, the icon displays the exact percentage of completion to the user. I find it unlikely that OP has given such a precise estimate, but rather, has directly read "36% complete" from the installation metre. **Ultimately, it is better to try and save a question, then burn it.**

Comment: @Timelord64 ok then...

Comment: I can also now confirm that while Battlefront does, initially, show a loading screen; it represents how much of the game has installed, and in fact, does include online content.

Answer (score 1):

**Your internet speed is likely at fault here.**

I have just installed the game, and here are my observations:

- It took about 30-45 minutes to install enough of the game to run, on an Xbox Elite console. Regular consoles may take a little longer, as the elites solid state drive performs faster, allowing quicker install and loading times.
- As of 1/4/2016, Battlefront requires approximately 8.5 GB of updates. This accounts for patches, as well as new content; There is at least one map (The Battle for Jaku) that was released as a free DLC, that was not immediately available with release. This took about an hour, for me. However, I have a fast cable internet connection, for where I live.
- The reported percentage on the Xbox Dashboard appears to be the percentage of game installed directly from the disc. When the Xbox reported "42% complete", Battlefront reported "12% complete".
- Both progress bars **are in no way designed to progress smoothly**. I had several pauses, before the bar would jump anywhere from 5% to 30% ahead of itself. I speculate that the bar represents chunks of varying sizes, so 5 updates would individually account for 20%, even if one update was considerably larger (and took a far greater time) than the other.
- At approximately 42% installed, you can actually play Battlefront. However, until you have completed the install, you are limited to a game of Darth Vader vs The Rebels. At this point, however, you can confirm that the game actually runs. Furthermore, as I said before, your given a more accurate progress bar in game.

### What if I have extremely slow internet, and wish to forgo the update?

At this point you want to be considering the capabilities of your internet. If you are experiencing considerably slow install times, as a result of internet speed, it is worth asking if you can normally get away with the speeds required to play a game online.

While many games will still force you to update, and disconnecting from the internet can forgo these extra loading period, Battlefront is predominantly an online game.

Answer (score -1):

Star Wars Battlefront only took me 5 hours to download on PS4 but my friends with an Xbox One had to wait a whole day for it to download so just leave it running for a day and you can come back to it and play